# What is the difference between exclude-result-prefixes and extension-element-prefix in XSLT namespace declaration?

Tags: xslt, namespaces, exslt

What's the difference between `exclude-result-prefixes` and `extension-element-prefix`? Both are used in the header of XSLTs. I've found `extension-element-prefix` while using EXSLT and the [EXSLT website Howto](http://www.exslt.org/howto.html#namespaces) says that `extension-element-prefix` is used for  "prevent the extension namespaces from being output in the result tree".

**But** this is not true (using libxslt). Only `exclude-result-prefixes` removes the extension namespace. So why do I need `extension-element-prefix` ???

Sample:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0"
  extension-element-prefix="exsl">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <blabla/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output with libxslt (xsltproc):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<blabla xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use EXSLT functions like the one in the namespace `http://exslt.org/common` you don't need the `extension-element-prefix` attribute. That is only need if you want to use extension elements like `func:function` in the namespace `http://exslt.org/functions`. The `extension-element-prefix` attribute simply signals that any elements with that prefix are not literals result elements but rather extension instructions in addition to those instructions defined by the XSLT language.

As for `exclude-result-prefixes`, you have understood that right, it helps avoiding any namespace declarations on your result elements for namespaces declared and used in the stylesheet solely to select nodes in path expressions or match patterns or used to insert extension elements.

Comment: Ah ok. This makes sense. I just wondered why I should use `extension-element-prefix` because I could remove it completely with `http://exslt.org/common`. Seems the EXSLT documentation is **wrong** at this part.

Comment: or `extension-element-prefix` only hides elements from output tree which need `extension-element-prefix`. To be on the save path I will use `extension-element-prefix` and `exclude-result-prefixes` both at the same time when I use extension libraries like EXSLT.

Comment: Some people use extension-element-prefixes all the time when they only need exclude-result-prefixes, and it works, because EEP has two effects: it allows you to use the namespace for extension elements (a privilege you can ignore), and it adds the namespace to the ERP list.